# Vue3 vue-router not rendering

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-router4

## Question

development environment

- vue 3.3.4
- vue-router@4
- IDE: vs-code 1.80

I'm following the [vue-router tutorial](https://vueschool.io/lessons/installing-and-setting-up-vue-router-with-vite-vite-only) as a demo, and the router-link renders, but the **router-view** does not.

There are no errors reported on the page or in the console.

Please help me see what's wrong, **thanks**!

## Files

### main.js

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import router from '@/router/indexRouter'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')
app.config.devtools = true
```

### indexRouter.js

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

import Home from '@/views/Home.vue'
import About from '@/views/About.vue'

const routes = [
    { path: '/', name: "Home", title: "Home", component: Home },
    { path: '/about', name: "About", component: About }
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
})

export default router
```

### App.vue

```html
<template>
  <h1>Hello App!</h1>
  <p>
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> | 
    <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
  </p>

  <router-view></router-view>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App'
}

</script>
```

### Home.vue

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
</template>
```

### About.vue

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>About</h1>
    </div>
</template>
```

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: If possible, could you create a codepen or codesandbox project where you can replicate the issue?

Comment: As far as I can see everything is well configured, have you tried restarting the compilation? Sometimes the compilation system fails and does not show an error as such.